# VBA PivotTable and PivotField - PivotField.CurrentPage not updating

Tags: excel, vba

So, I am trying to use the Pivot Table to set the necessary filter conditions for a query and then retrieve the value.

The SetFilter macro works perfectly when called from a Test Macro and executed using the Run function.

```
Public Sub SetFilter(tpt As PivotField, astr As Variant)
    tpt.ClearAllFilters
    If astr <> "All" Then
        tpt.CurrentPage = astr
    Else
        tpt.CurrentPage = "(All)"
    End If
End
```

However, when part of a query function, tpt.clearallfilters crashes and the attempt to set tpt.CurrentPage also fails ..

I'm at my wits end.  I suspect it's to do with scope but using the debugger didn't show anything obvious that would prevent me setting the PageField.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"When part of a query function"* - could you give an example?

Comment: pvtquerystr = "Sum of " & valuename

    With Worksheets("Pivot Summary").PivotTables("PivotDB")
    .ManualUpdate = False

    success = ItemExists(.PivotFields("Device Category"), device)
    success = success And ItemExists(.PivotFields("Engine"), engine)
  
If success Then
    Call SetFilter(.PivotFields("Device Category"), device)
    Call SetFilter(.PivotFields("Engine"), engine)
    SDBPivotQuery = .GetPivotData(pvtquerystr).value 
    Else
        SDBPivotQuery = 0
    
    End If

    End With
    
                                        
    End Function

Comment: So, if called from a simple test macro directly, using run macro, all works fine.  When called from the query function (which I've shortened) it doesn't work at all and crashes